# Add a rule for unique values, jquery validate in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-validate

I want to have a rule so that repeated values are not allowed in the text fields. I tried to put the rule to validate unique values, but it still does not work. I have seen other forums but the solutions they propose do not work for me.

```
$scope.data=[
 {"number": 33},{"number": 33},{"number": 44}
]

var aUnique=[];
for (var i in $scope.data){
 if(aUnique.indexOf($scope.data[i].number)==-1){
  aUnique.push($scope.data[i].number)
 }
}

$scope.validar= function(){

$('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    field: {
      required: "Enter something"
    }
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().addClass("errorl");
  },
  unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().removeClass("errorl");
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) { 
 }
});

 $.validator.addMethod("unique", function(value, element) {

  if(aUnique.indexOf(value)==-1){
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
 }, "only unique");

$(".inputtext").each(function() {
   $(this).rules('add', { required: true,unique:true }    )                  
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/o082rrv0/

Comment: angular and jquery do not mix well... you should consider using angular's amazing built-in validation engine.

Comment: Please explain "does not work" in great detail.  What are the expected results versus what results do you see?

Comment: Your jsFiddle is not working at all.... there is no validation.  I think you should at least get validation initialized and working with a simple `required` rule first before worrying about custom rules.